'clas_name': is not a class or namespace name when trying to build macro in C++
I have this macro:
    #define CONCAT_CLSS(clss, mtd) &clss::mtd
    #define EXPORT_X(getter, setter, class_name, arg_name,set,get)                    \
        godot::ClassDB::bind_method(godot::D_METHOD(getter), CONCAT_CLSS(clas_name,get)); \
        godot::ClassDB::bind_method(godot::D_METHOD(setter, arg_name),  CONCAT_CLSS(clas_name,set)); \
        ADD_PROPERTY(godot::PropertyInfo(godot::Variant::FLOAT, arg_name), setter, getter);


//when calling it from : 
void Plaine::_bind_methods()
    {
         
        EXPORT_X("get_gravity","set_gravity", Plaine, "gravity", set_gravity, get_gravity)
    }

This defined in different class:
#define ADD_PROPERTY(m_property, m_setter, m_getter) godot::ClassDB::add_property(get_class_static(), m_property, m_setter, m_getter)

I don't understand why it complains about the class name here. Also how can I make this macro shorter.
I'm getting this error:
plane.cpp
src\plane.cpp(33): error C2653: 'clas_name': is not a class or namespace name

Now the class does exist as I call from it.

You could ask the compiler to show you the preprocessed code, so you know how the macro is expanded.

how can i do it in vc++ 2022?

Typo: clas_name -> class_name
For example:
+ CONCAT_CLSS(class_name,get)
- CONCAT_CLSS(clas_name,get)


There's no need to answer typo questions. Just add a comment, then flag as typo if you have enough rep to vote in that way.
